# Where should I handle capitalization of words in rails applications?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, capitalization

As far as I know there are many ways:

1. Directly in the code: this could work only if the application doesn't need to be internationalized, but it's not the best, I think.
2. In the localization files: I've run into the problem that when I internationalize a model, and I have buttons like `Create %{model}`, if the model has more than one word, it may look awkward if only the first letter is capitalized.
3. In the code using humanize or titleize: It may lead to capitalization of sentences like `Create And Continue`, capitalizing the `And` when you could want to say something like `Create and Continue` or `Create and continue`.
4. Trough CSS: I thought this was the best place because capitalization is part of the style of the page (or not?) and it's similar to use humanize or titleize but you still have the same problems than these.

I've tried them and I've had difficulties with all of them. Especially because there exists acronyms that shouldn't be transformed to lowercase and articles that looks a little ugly when capitalized.

Also, sometimes you want to use the same words but capitalized them different. In this case should be better to use two different entries in the locale files or use 3 or 4 to change them?

When using the 4th option I found difficult to write tests because the html has everything lowercased but it's not really like that. Cucumber doesn't parse CSS to check the style of words.

Answer (score 0):

What is wrong with putting it in the localization? Put each text as you want it to appear on the site, and you're set. If you write the text yourself, there should be no need to programmatically mangle it afterwards.

As for the models: Put [human readable names](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html#translations-for-active-record-models) into the translations for each of them. Also, if you think they need to be capitalized differently in some place - capitalize just the model name, not the entire button text.